# Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while using Repository annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebStore</display-name>
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml
   </param-value>
  </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"></mvc:annotation-driven>
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt"/>

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
  
  

</beans>
```

I am new to spring, and I getting errors while adding `@Repository` annotation

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
    Dependency annotation {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="ProductRepository")}
```

The code is given below :

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository;

@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl","com.packt.webstore.domain.repository"})
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ProductRepository")
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products",productRepository.getAllProducts());
        return "products";
    }
}



package com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;
import com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository;

@Component
@Repository
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepository {


    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate=new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Map<String, Object>params=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        List<Product>result=jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS", params, new ProductMapper());
        return result;
    }

    private static final class ProductMapper implements org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<Product> {
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rownum) throws SQLException{
            Product product=new Product();
            product.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            return product;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your code, Where the error is occurring and try to post your code in code blocks. `something like this`

Comment: Apparently its dependency injection issue you are facing. Share your code where you are failing to inject the dependency

Comment: Here is my code:

Comment: This is not a code, this is an error. Additional, share your config class

Comment: I added code please look into it.

Comment: Add `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation to your `ProductRepository` interface.

Answer (score 3):

Either keep `@Component` or `@Repository` in the `ProductRepositoryImpl`. Both is not possible.

In addition to that, keep camelcase like this `@Qualifier("productRepository")`.

Remove `@ComponentScan` from the Controller. It should be in the Java Config.

Example of Java - Based Config :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.packt")
public class Config {

}
```

If using XML-Based Config, then do the down below :

Update `applicationContext.xml` or any `servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Spring Application Context File -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Added support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt" />
</beans>
```

If this is not working, then check your custom servlet XML files or `applicationContext.xml` with `web.xml` for configuration errors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208406/discussion-on-answer-by-anish-b-spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-while-usin).